# How to create document in couchbase using java code

Tags: java, couchbase

I tried below code:

```
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env,"localhost:8091");
Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("example","");

JsonObject person = JsonObject.create();
person.put("firstname","JK");
person.put("lastname","Haza");
```

OUTPUT IS :

```
{
   "firstname": "Jk",
   "lastname": "Haza"
}1
```

But I need below json format :

```
Person {   "firstname": "JAyu",   "lastname": "Hazari" }
```

Answer (score 0):

The format you indicate you need is not actually JSON.

This would be a valid JSON object:

`{
 "Person": {
   "firstname": "Jk", 
   "lastname": "Haza"
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the JSON object to be in the format indicated by Matt, this is the code you need:

```
JsonObject person = JsonObject.create();
person.put("firstname","JK");
person.put("lastname","Haza");
JsonObject personContainer = JsonObject.create();
personContainer .put("person", person);
```